# Java - Intelij Idea - Maven build fails on "cannot access *library class* " , but library is imported correctly (org.apache.jen)

Tags: java, maven, class, intellij-idea, jena

Im using apache-jena-libs library version 4.3.2(tried various versions). I've imported it as maven pom dependecny

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And it has successfuly loaded(no errors)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h29Gp.png)
imports are fine as well, no errors there

```
import org.apache.jena.riot.*;
import org.apache.jena.graph.*;
```

but when I actually use library in code as such:

```
@Override
    public synchronized void add(Reader reader, String fullFilePath, RDFFormat dataFormat, Resource... contexts) throws IOException, RDFParseException, RepositoryException {
        this.verifyIsOpen();
        this.flushDelayAdd();
//        final boolean useStatementContext = contexts != null && contexts.length == 0;
        IRI graphIri = (IRI) Arrays.stream(contexts).findFirst().get();
        try {
            Graph gf = Factory.createDefaultGraph();
            org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.create()
                    .source(fullFilePath)
                    .forceLang(org.apache.jena.riot.Lang.JSONLD11)
                    .base(graphIri.stringValue())
                    .parse(gf);
            gf.close();
            ...
```

Everything looks fine but during maven clean-install I get error "cannot access org.apache.jena.graph.Graph".

This method is a part of the standart public class(no bean).
Im using Intelij Idea 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) with JDK 1.8 and maven 3.8.1.
This problem I am encountering is only with this library, tried to search for answers but havent found anything exactly like this. Does anyone have any clue what could be wrong please?

Comment: did you run mvn clean install from the command line directly or via idea?

Comment: only in idea. Tried to run it in command line and it shows additional info - class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0 ..so i guess the problem is that this library was compiled in java 11 while i am using java 8. Thank you.

Comment: Note that in IDEA that additional information is almost certainly printed too, but sometimes you have to click on a higher tree element in the "tree of build steps" to the left of the console to see the full output. That nasty detail has hidden many relevant pieces of information from me over the years.

Comment: If you managed to solve your own question, please don't add things like _"(resolved)"_ to the question title. Either delete your question (e.g. if it was a typo), or **answer** your own question describing - in detail - how you solved the problem.

Comment: Apache Jena 4 requires Java11.